# Rspec and Capybara throw inconsistent Postgresql errors each time I run my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, selenium, rspec, capybara

Postgresql throws various errors or stalls I run my feature test suite which uses Rspec, Capybara-Selenium, and DatabaseCleaner. I can't pin it down because the error changes every time. Sometimes there are no errors at all. I would appreciate any guidance out there.

Here's Error1:

```
Processing by Api::V1::Company::WagesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"wage"=>{"user_id"=>33, "amount"=>"100000"}, "user_id"=>"33"}
(39.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
(1.8ms)  BEGIN
NoMethodError: undefined method `nfields' for nil:NilClass:             SELECT tablename
        FROM pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname = ANY (current_schemas(false))

  SQL (12.6ms)  INSERT INTO "wages" ("amount", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["amount", "100000.0"], ["created_at", "2014-06-17 19:47:21.901609"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-17 19:47:21.901609"], ["user_id", 33]]
  (5.1ms)  COMMIT
```

Error2:

```
 Started POST "/api/v1/company/users/2/wages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-17 15:51:32 -0400
 Processing by Api::V1::Company::WagesController#create as JSON
 Parameters: {"wage"=>{"user_id"=>2, "amount"=>"100000"}, "user_id"=>"2"}
 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "id" does not exist
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"wages"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Error3:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NoActiveSqlTransaction: ERROR:  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT can only be used in transaction blocks
: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_0
  occurred at /Users/codylittlewood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@bitcoinpayroll/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
```

Error4: (where it just hangs)

```
(3.2ms)  ALTER TABLE "companies" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations"     DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "payrolls" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "payslips" DISABLE    TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "users" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "wages" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
   (18.5ms)  TRUNCATE TABLE "companies", "payrolls", "payslips", "users", "wages" RESTART   IDENTITY CASCADE;
Started POST "/api/v1/company/users/4/wages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-17 15:57:41 -0400
Processing by Api::V1::Company::WagesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"wage"=>{"user_id"=>4, "amount"=>"100000"}, "user_id"=>"4"}
```

No code was changed between any of these tests and different errors each time.

Here's my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'    
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|    
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures" 

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Here's my feature tests `spec/features/user_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'          
include Warden::Test::Helpers  
Warden.test_mode!              

feature  'Employee management' do
  scenario "adds a new user", :js => true do
    admin = create(:admin)     
    admin.confirmed_at = Time.now   
    admin.save                 
    login_as(admin, :scope => :user)


    visit root_path            

    expect{
      #click_link 'Dashboard'  
      click_link 'Company employees'  
      click_link 'Add an employee'    
      fill_in 'employee[first_name]', with: 'Test'
      fill_in 'employee[last_name]', with: 'User'
      fill_in 'employee[email]', with: 'newuser@example.com'
      select "January", from: 'employee[hire_month]'
      select "1", from: 'employee[hire_day]' 
      select "2014", from: 'employee[hire_year]'
      fill_in 'employee[wage]', with: '100000'
      click_button 'Add employee'     
    }.to change(User, :count).by(1) 
    logout :admin
  end
end
Warden.test_reset!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks as though there are multiple threads trying to access the same database connection at once, and it's mixing queries. There's no reason for those queries to happen simultaneously.

Maybe check out your code to see if there's something creating a shared connection? See if literally commenting out the shared connection code works?

Comment: That worked. I had `shared_db_connection` in `spec/support` following the example given in Everyday Rails testing with Rspec book. Commented this file out and it worked.